# What is the best way to backup a DVD for XBMC?

Tags: backup, kodi

I have [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) running on a Mac mini running OS X, and I'd like to make our DVDs (and eventually our video cassettes) accessible, so that our five-year-old can start her movies by herself.

I first tried copying the data contents of the DVD, but XBMC doesn't do any magic when it encounters these folders.  It is playable, but it is more like picking a filename, not picking a movie.

Next I'll try a straight .ISO file, but I'm hoping someone else has been down this road and has some tips.  I'm most comfortable with Linux tools, but if there is a better program on Windows or OS X, I'd check it out.

Comment: Are you using the movie library functionality or file system browsing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you copy the contents of the DVD into a folder it should be handled as a DVD. If you select the folder and press play it will launch it as a dvd, if you use the "enter" button it will list the contents of the folder.

Comment: I'm marking this as the accepted answer, because XBMC does handle DVDs copied in this manner, but you have to tell it.  See http://xbmc.org/wiki/?title=Set_Content_%28Video_Library%29 .  
However, after using it this way for a about a month, I think it's more useful in most cases to use Handbrake or another tool to turn the DVD into a single file, unless you really like watching previews, warnings, and finally navigating the DVD menu.

Comment: Instructions moved to http://wiki.xbmc.org/?title=Set_Content_(Video_Library)

Answer (score 4):

I really can recommend [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) for ripping the DVD's. I use it to put all our DVD's on [TVersity](http://tversity.com/) streamed to XBMC, however it can also be read by XBMC directly once done, and you can take out all the menu's and unnecessary sections.

Comment: I recently tried Handbrake on a Mac, and it worked quite nicely.  I used version 0.9.4, the 64-bit build.  It also required a 64-bit version of VLC for the deCSS libraries.  The latest version of VLC (see comment date) is 1.0.3, but the latest with a 64-bit build was 1.0.2.  It took about 90 minutes to transcode a 2 hour movie.  This is the way to go, unless you really like the DVD menus, in which case, disk space being cheap, just keep both around.

Answer (score 2):

There is discussion on [**DVD Copy Integration**](http://www.xbmc.org/forum/showthread.php?t=34960&page=2) at the **XBMC** forum
that refers to [**Handbrake**](http://handbrake.fr) and [**MythTV**](http://www.mythtv.org).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a dvd ripper. After a bit of googling [MacTheRipper](http://www.versiontracker.com/dyn/moreinfo/macosx/22715) looks like a pretty good one for OSX. You should be able to rip the dvd to a .avi and put it somewhere XBMC will find it.